# If $\sup S\not\in S$ then $\{x \in S: x > \sup{S} - \epsilon\}$ is infinite

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing, supremum-and-infimum

Let $S\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ be nonempty and bounded above, and let $\beta = \sup{S}$. Suppose that $\beta \not\in S$. Prove that for each $\epsilon > 0,$ the set $\{x \in S: x > \beta - \epsilon\}$ is infinite.

So far I had started with the fact that $\beta$ was the supremum of $S$ and that by definition $\beta - \epsilon$ must be an element of $S.$ Since $S\subseteq\mathbb{R},$ which is infinite, and this set is a subset of $S,$ it seems like this set should be infinite for each $\epsilon.$ But how do I show this?

Comment: I don't think that $(\beta - \epsilon) \in S$ by definition of supremum. Also just because $S \subset \mathbb{R}$ and is not empty does not mean that it is infinite. In terms of going about the proof, look back at the definition of supremum and see what happens if you assume that $\{x \in S : x > \beta - \epsilon\}$ is finite or empty.

Comment: Oh. If {x ∈S: x > β - ϵ} is empty wouldn't that mean that β - ϵ is an upper bound of S so β couldn't be the supremum?

Comment: A key hypothesis is that $\beta\notin S$. You should use it since the result fails without it.

Comment: $\beta - \epsilon$ does not have to be in S.  Consider $S = \{1 - 1/n\}$ then sup S = 1.  But $\beta - 3/20= 17/20$ is not in S.

Comment: Should I be looking for a contradiction to arise from that then? Or would that be used in a direct proof?

Comment: What the definition *does* say is that there must exist a y in S such that $\beta - \epsilon < y \le \beta$.  Since $\beta \not \in S$.  $\beta - \epsilon < y < \beta$.

Comment: Hint:  Take an infinite number of epsilons....

Comment: {x in S: x > beta - eps} is indeed never empty by the definition of suprememum.  But that doesn't mean beta - eps, itself, is on S.

Comment: That is true. But how is the set infinite for each $\epsilon$? I could understand that if we were looking at the real numbers themselves, but as a subset, isn't there no guarantee that there is such an infinite amount of numbers between beta-eps and the maximum?

Answer (score 4):

By definition of $\sup$, each such set is non-empty.
Assume that for some specific $\epsilon>0$, the set is finite. Then let $m$ be its maximum. By assumption, $m<\sup S$. What can you say about $\{\,x\in S:x>\sup S-(\sup S-m)\,\}$?

Comment: Well if m is the maximum of the set, wouldn't that set be empty?

Comment: Since that would be looking at the x's strictly greater than the maximum of the set?

Answer (score 1):

**Proposition**. Let $ S\subseteq \mathbb{R} $ be nonempty and bounded above. (Because $ \mathbb{R} $ has the least upper bound property) Let $ \beta $ be the least upper bound of $ S $. If $ \beta\notin S $, then $ \left\{x\in S:x>\beta-\epsilon\right\} $ is infinite for every $ \epsilon>0 $.

*Proof*.
Assume $ \beta\notin S $.
Let $ \epsilon>0 $ be arbitrary.
By contradiction, suppose $ \left\{x\in S:x>\beta-\epsilon\right\} $ is finite.
That set is nonempty because otherwise $\beta$ is not the least upper bound of $S$.
Because every finite (nonempty) totally ordered set has a greatest element, let $ \beta_0 $ be the greatest element in $ \left\{x\in S:x>\beta-\epsilon\right\} $.
Notice $ \beta_0 $ is an upper bound of $ S $.
Because $ \beta $ is the least upper bound of $ S $, $ \beta\le \beta_0 $.
Notice $ \beta_0\in S $.
Because $ \beta $ is an upper bound of $ S $, $ \beta_0\le S $.
So $ \beta_0=\beta $.
Therefore $ \beta\in S $---a contradiction.
As a result, $ \left\{x\in S:x>\beta-\epsilon\right\} $ is infinite.